# Query which tells us how many people work in the same department that 'Gomes' is working in

Tags: mysql

```
Create database "EmpDB01";
use [EmpDB01];

Create Table LOCATION (
    "CITY-ID"   varchar(50) NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY,
    "CITY-NAME" varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

Insert Into LOCATION
Values  ('C10', 'Los Angeles'),
        ('C20', 'Karachi'),
        ('C30', 'Lahore');

Create Table DEPT (
    "DEPTNO"    varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "DEPTNAME"  varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "CITY-ID"   varchar(50) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES LOCATION("CITY-ID")
);

Insert Into DEPT
Values  ('10',  'Sales',            'C10'),
        ('20',  'Administration',   'C20'),
        ('30',  'Software',         'C30'),
        ('40',  'Finance',          'C30');

Create Table EMP (
    "EMPNO"     varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    "ENAME"     varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "Gender"    varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "JOB"       varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "MGR"       varchar(50),
    "SALARY"    int         NOT NULL,
    "COMM"      int,
    "DEPTNO"    varchar(50) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DEPT("DEPTNO")
);

Insert Into EMP
Values  ('7201',    'Alice',    'F',    'Clerk',            '7202', 30000,  NULL,       '20'),
        ('7101',    'Bob',      'M',    'Salesman',         '7102', 50000,  '10000',    '10'),
        ('7102',    'Chris',    'M',    'Manager',          '7205', 75000,  NULL,       '10'),
        ('7202',    'David',    'M',    'Manager',          '7205', 75000,  NULL,       '20'),
        ('7203',    'Earl',     'M',    'President',         NULL,  150000, NULL,       '20'),
        ('7301',    'Frederic', 'M',    'Analyst',          '7303', 65000,  NULL,       '30'),
        ('7302',    'Gomes',    'M',    'Programmer',       '7303', 50000,  NULL,       '30'),
        ('7204',    'Helen',    'F',    'Accoutant',        '7202', 50000,  NULL,       '20'),
        ('7303',    'Intikhab', 'M',    'Manager',          '7205', 75000,  NULL,       '30'),
        ('7401',    'Jamie',    'F',    'Manager',          '7205', 65000,  NULL,       '40'),
        ('7205',    'Kyle',     'F',    'Vice President',   '7203', 100000, NULL,       '20'),
        ('7402',    'Linda',    'F',    'Financial Asst.',  '7401', 40000,  NULL,       '40');

Select *
From DEPT
Select *
From LOCATION
Select *
From EMP
```

> I am using this data and I want to get this:
>   6. tells us how many people work in the same department that 'Gomes' is working in.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support qouted column names i think you are using SQL-server.

Comment: @RaymondNijland You can [enable ANSI quotes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) as an option, but few people ever do that. SQL Server tends to use `[name]` style quoting.

Comment: @tadman learned something new about MySQL today. `SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',ANSI_QUOTES');` indeed makes this possible `CREATE TABLE test ("id" INT);`.. i knew MSSQL uses brackets `[]` to make it possible the use reserved keywords

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yeah, there's a lot of very infrequently used options in there that can make MySQL behave very *strangely* if you're not expecting that. The ANSI quote mode is why you need a database connection for your driver to know how to quote strings properly: The way that's done can and will change, assuming `'` and `\\'` for literal quotes is a huge mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using SQL-server because off the qouted column names. 
But these queries should work in most if not all databases.

Use IN

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(*)
FROM 
 EMP 
WHERE
 DEPTNO IN (
  SELECT 
   DEPTNO
  FROM 
    EMP
  WHERE
    ENAME = 'Gomes'
 ) 
 AND
  ENAME <> 'Gomes'
```

**Result**

```
|   |
|---|
| 2 |
```

Or with a JOIN

**Query**

```
SELECT
 COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT 
   DEPTNO
  FROM 
    EMP
  WHERE
    ENAME = 'Gomes'
)
 EMP_Gomes
INNER JOIN 
 EMP
ON
  EMP_Gomes.DEPTNO = EMP.DEPTNO
WHERE
 EMP.ENAME <> 'Gomes'
```

**Result**

```
|   |
|---|
| 2 |
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7ca3/13